# How do I make sure a frame is fullscreen?

Tags: frames, fullscreen

The command `#'toggle-frame-fullscreen` does exactly what it says; it *toggles* between fullscreen and not.

What command can I run to make sure the frame is fullscreen? That is, if not fullscreen, make it fullscreen; if already fullscreen, don't do anything.

Comment: It is the first line of code after the `interactive` statement -- i.e., evaluate `(frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen)`.  If not fullscreen, then it will return `nil`.  To see what is happening, type `M-x find-function RET toggle-frame-fullscreen RET`

Comment: I found an exception to the above-mentioned comment in the case of a `maximized` frame (but not full screen).  Here is a revised test that will return `nil` if the frame is `maximized` (or less), or `t` if it is fullscreen:  `(memq (frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen) '(fullscreen fullboth))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Properties of frames are called [frame parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Frame-Parameters.html). Whether a frame is maximized this way or not is controlled by the `'fullscreen` [parameter](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Size-Parameters.html#Size-Parameters). We want this parameter to be `'fullboth`. And we can [set](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Parameter-Access.html#Parameter-Access) a frame parameter using `#'set-frame-parameter`.

So here's code to make sure the `'fullscreen` parameter is `'fullboth`:

```
(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'fullboth)
```