# Setting frame at fullscreen without toggle

Tags: frames

How can I maximize the current frame in an idempotent manner? That is to say, it maximizes the frame if it isn't, and leaves the frame maximized if it is?

Comment: Search first, then ask.

Comment: Also this one: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51392/how-do-i-toggle-between-current-frame-size-and-maximized-frame/

Comment: What is the difference between maximised and fullscreen ?

Comment: "*What is the difference between maximised and fullscreen ?*" -- Can't you google yourself?

Comment: I do not know the correct terminology, but maximised retains a bar at the top with an emacs logo.  What is it ?

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the comments, there are existing questions that lead the way to the answer to this one.

[How do I toggle between current frame size and maximized frame](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/51392/how-do-i-toggle-between-current-frame-size-and-maximized-frame/) teaches us that there is `toggle-frame-maximized`.

[How do I make sure a frame is fullscreen?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/29624/how-do-i-make-sure-a-frame-is-fullscreen) teaches us that there is a function `set-frame-parameter`.

When we look at the help for `toggle-frame-maximized` with `C-h f toggle-frame-maximized RET`, we see the following at the top:

> toggle-frame-maximized is an interactive byte-compiled Lisp function
> in ‘frame.el’.

This tells us the function is written in elisp, so we can go look at the source code by clicking on `frame.el`, right there.

When we go look at the source code for `toggle-frame-maximized`, we see that it fundamentally is a conditional that has three possible calls to `set-frame-parameter`.

In order to unconditionally maximize the current frame, all we need to do is the following:

`(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)`

That's it.